# Vue JS v-for filter by unique

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

My company is moving from Angular JS to Vue. It has been very smooth until I needed to replicate the functionailty of an Angular filter into VueJS. The original Angular filter looked like so:

JS

```
app.filter('unique', function () {
    return function (collection, keyname) {
        var output = [],
            keys = [];

        angular.forEach(collection, function (item) {
            var key = item[keyname];
            if (keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                keys.push(key);
                output.push(item);
            }
        });

        return output;
    };
});
```

In my Vue I have the following:

```
<select class="u-full-width" v-model="newPost.cat">
   <option value="" selected="selected">Choose a Category</option>
   <option v-for="post in posts | unique" selected>{{ post.cat }}</option>
</select>
```

I assume I can still use filters the same, but how do I go about replicating this?

Comment: What do you mean replicating this? And i thing in Vue2 filters are not supported, and you can use computed methods

Comment: Replicate may not be the right word, "mimicking the functionality" may be better. I want to achieve same thing I did in Angular in Vue system.

Comment: check answer by Tomasz Rup, this is propadly most conventional way for vuejs2. In vuejs version 1 was filter similar to angularjs 1, but in version 2 was deprecated - you can check this tutorial [filters ways in vue2](https://www.codecourse.com/lessons/filters-in-vue-2)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use a computed property here. Filters in Vue are, as stated by the creator, supposed to be for text transformation mainly (not a rule of course, but I'd still go with a computed property).

On your component:

```
  computed: {
    uniquePosts: function() {
      var output = [];
      var keys   = [];

      this.posts.forEach(function (post) {
          var key = post[keyname];

          if (keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
              keys.push(key);
              output.push(post);
          }
      });

      return output;
    }
  }
```

And `v-for` the `uniquePosts` in your template.

**EDIT:**
To pass a `keyname`:

```
computed: {
   uniquePosts: function () {
      var vm = this;
      return function (keyname) {
         var output = [];
         var keys   = [];

         vm.posts.forEach(function (post) {
             var key = post[keyname];

             if (keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                 keys.push(key);
                 output.push(post);
             }
         });

         return output;
      };
   }
}
```

And you can call `uniquePosts(keyname)`.

**EDIT2:** Fixed variable names, sorry

Comment: Wow, that is a bit different than Angular. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

To improve on Tomasz' answer, you might define a [global mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Global-Mixin) in your main.js:

```
Vue.mixin({
  computed: {
    unique () {
      return function (arr, key) {
        var output = []
        var usedKeys = {}
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          if (!usedKeys[arr[i][key]]) {
            usedKeys[arr[i][key]] = true
            output.push(arr[i])
          }
        }
        return output
      }
    }
  }
})
```

In any of your components, pass in the array to filter and the property to filter on in:

```
<option v-for="post in unique(posts, 'cat')" selected>{{ post.cat }}</option>
```

Using an object to check which unique keys have been added should be more efficient than `indexOf` which has to search the array.  Keep in mind you might want to make a Plugin instead of using a global mixin as the Vue docs recommend.