# v-for loop display only unique items vue js

Tags: html, vue.js

Am trying to display icons based on the v-for and v-if conditions , but the icons are displayed multiple times , i need to display only the unique ones.

I tried v-if = 'index === 0' but instead this doesn't work

```html
<div v-for="(bits, index) in inv.auction.Bits" :key="index">
  <div v-if="bits.iswin == true && bits.userid == d.userid">
    <b-tooltip label="mine" position="is-right">
      <b-icon class="iswinclass" icon="thumb-up" type="is-success"></b-icon>
    </b-tooltip>  
  </div>  
  <div v-if="bits.iswin == false && bits.userid == d.userid">
    <b-tooltip label="mine" position="is-right">
      <b-icon class="iswinclass" icon="thumb-down" type="is-danger"></b-icon>
    </b-tooltip>  
  </div> 
</div>
```

I want one thumb-up and one thumb-down to display if the condition matches instead multiple icons are displayed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue JS v-for filter by unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42845338/vue-js-v-for-filter-by-unique)

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code. Have you used vue-devtools to check the component's data values?

Comment: Can you please explain what _"the icons are displayed multiple times"_ means? What sort of data is in `inv.auction.Bits`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have multiple items in `inv.auction.Bits` that match `d.userid` but you only want to show one each of your icons if there are any matches.

I would, instead of looping `inv.auction.Bits`, create two computed properties to determine when to show your icons.

For example

```js
computed: {
  showThumbsUp() {
    return this.inv.auction.Bits.some(({ iswin, userid }) =>
        iswin && userid === this.d.userid)
  },
  showThumbsDown() {
    return this.inv.auction.Bits.some(({ iswin, userid }) =>
        !iswin && userid === this.d.userid)
  }
}
```

and in your template (no `v-for`)

```html
<div v-if="showThumbsUp">
  <b-tooltip label="mine" position="is-right">
    <b-icon class="iswinclass" icon="thumb-up" type="is-success"></b-icon>
  </b-tooltip>  
</div>  
<div v-if="showThumbsDown">
  <b-tooltip label="mine" position="is-right">
    <b-icon class="iswinclass" icon="thumb-down" type="is-danger"></b-icon>
  </b-tooltip>  
</div>
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)